# Linq query : select content of an ID when max(date)

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Happy new Year everyone ! :-)

I've searched for several hours but I can't figure out how to build my query properly using Linq.

I have 2 tables : A and B

**In table A :** I have A_ID, B_ID, VALUE_DATE.

**In table B :** I have B_ID, STATUS.

*Example :*

***A_ID*** = 547  **VALUE_DATE** = 01/05/10 **B_ID** = 14750

***A_ID*** = 547  **VALUE_DATE** = 01/10/10 **B_ID** = 14750

I want to join A and B using B_ID where VALUE_DATE is max.
At the moment, this is what I have :

context is OracleDataContextCommon object
evalId and listAffId are parameters of my webservice method.

```
var query = (from tabA in (from a in context.A
                          where listAffId.Contains(a.A_ID)
                          group a by a.A_IDinto grp
                          select new
                          {
                              pId = (int)grp.Key,
                              valDate = grp.Max(x => x.ValueDate),
                              bId = grp.Select(x => B_ID).FirstOrDefault()
                          })
                         join tabB in context.B on tabA.bIdequals equals tabB.B_ID
                         select new
                         {
                             affId = tabA.pId,
                             status = tabB.Status
                         });
```

Where am I wrong ? Thank you for investigate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the `B_ID` that is for the max date, so find the max date first:

```
var query = (from tabA in (from a in context.A
                          where listAffId.Contains(a.A_ID)
                          group a by a.A_IDinto grp
                          let maxdate = grp.Max(a => a.ValueDate)
                          select new
                          {
                              pId = (int)grp.Key,
                              valDate = maxdate,
                              bId = grp.Where(a => a.ValueDate == maxdate).Select(x => B_ID).FirstOrDefault()
                          })
                         join tabB in context.B on tabA.bId equals equals tabB.B_ID
                         select new
                         {
                             affId = tabA.pId,
                             status = tabB.Status
                         });
```

Comment: I ignored about the 'let' statement, it's great man, thank you ! I was trying to use grp.Where(...) but could not figure out next step. You did it pretty easily... :-)
I accepted your answer and upvoted you !

Comment: `let` isn't my favorite (it is normally implemented by doing a `select` to a new temporary object (if you want to do it in lambda), but I suppose SQL translation handles that for non-object cases), but it is very useful when needed for DRY or factoring our expensive operations (see [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform))

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're taking the max Date of the Group, but you are selecting the `FirstOrDefault` *B_ID* in the group, which doesn't necessarily correlate with the A row which had the max date. Easiest is probably to just order the data by date descending before grouping, and then take the first item in each group for both date and `b_id`.

Note that I've switched your context for with some dummy data below.

```
var theAs = new[]
{
   new {A_ID = 547, ValueDate = new DateTime(2010, 05, 01), B_ID = 14750}, 
   new {A_ID = 547, ValueDate = new DateTime(2010, 10, 01), B_ID = 14751}
};
var theBs = new[]
{
  new {B_ID = 14750, Status = "Foo"}, 
  new {B_ID = 14751, Status = "Bar"}
};
var listAffId = new[]{547};

var query = (from tabA in (from a in theAs
             where listAffId.Contains(a.A_ID)
             // Order the data - the first row per group is thus max date
             orderby a.ValueDate descending
             group a by a.A_ID into grp
             select new
             {
                 pId = (int)grp.Key,
                 // Now pull the date and B_ID from the same row
                 valDate = grp.First().ValueDate,
                 bId = grp.First().B_ID
             })
             join tabB in theBs on tabA.bId equals tabB.B_ID
             select new
             {
                 affId = tabA.pId,
                 status = tabB.Status
             });
```

Comment: This is something I thought about, I'm not familiar with Linq I would have like to get rid of FirstOrDefault but inference type fails on join if I don't use this kind of single-row selector... :-/ .
Thank you a lot for your solution, it sounds like a workaround (because I didn't want to sort my result) but it can save :-) . I upvoted you !

Answer (score 1):

I simulated code with classes.  I think this should work

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Context context = new Context();
            List<int> listAffId = new List<int>() { 547 };

            var query = (from a in context.A where listAffId.Contains(a.A_ID)
                         join b in context.B on a.B_ID equals b.B_ID
                         select new { a = a, b = b})
                         .GroupBy(x => x.a.A_ID)
                         .Select(x => new { x = x, max = x.Max(y => y.a.VALUE_DATE)})
                         .Select(x => new {
                             affId = x.x.Key,
                             status = x.x.Where(y => y.a.VALUE_DATE == x.max).Select(y => y.b.STATUS).FirstOrDefault()
                         }).ToList();



        }
    }
    public class Context
    {
        public List<TableA> A { get; set; }
        public List<TableB> B { get; set; }
    }
    public class TableA
    {
        public int A_ID { get; set; }
        public int B_ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime VALUE_DATE { get; set; }
    }
    public class TableB
    {
        public int B_ID { get; set; }
        public string STATUS { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the work man, it looks like the answer above, i wanted to avoid the sorting step (there are a lot of records in the table). I upvoted you ! :-)

Comment: I modified code to eliminate the full sort and use max.  My code is a lot simpler using one from instead of two nested from.  The execution time goes from N * N/2 (sort) to (3/2)N (search once through entire list for max then find max)

Comment: Indeed, nice one ! :-)

Comment: Sorting should be O(N * log N), don't think there will be any bubble sort here!

Comment: I'm not sure if the following code get execute N times or the optimizer will remove the redundancy : x.Max(z => z.a.VALUE_DATE).  I can move code so it only gets compiled once.

Comment: I don't trust the optimizer so I made slight change.

Comment: I moved the where to optimize a little better.